# How to get rid of rounded edges in Inkskape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes, corners

I was just trying to draw a square in Inkskape; so I clicked on *create rectangles and squares* and drew a square like this:

[image]

But I still get rounded edges. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it? All i want is a perfect square.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inkscape remembers the last settings used, and when you create a rectangle its corners have the same properties of the last rectangles you made.

You can get rid of the angles in several ways. Three of them are available when the button used to create rectangles is down, see also [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html_old/Shapes-Rectangles.html).

[image: create rectangle]

**1.** You can click on **Make corners sharp** button, as evidenced *user-unknonwn*, and get sharp corners immediately:

[image: Make corners sharp button]

**2.** You can **put to zero both the radii Rx and Ry** of the curvature:

[image: change radii]

**3.** Alternatively, you can **tweak the control points** of the radii until done:

[image]

Next rectangles will be with straight corners:

[image]

You can also change the defaults for new objects using the **Preferences** (*Edit* -> *Preferences* or **Shift-Ctrl-P**):

[image: rectangle preferences]

Comment: i just went to Stroke style and set joint to Minter Join

Comment: Milter, Round and Bevel Joint apply to the corners. See [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Stroke.html).

Comment: In Fig. 2, you see a corner, right to the Ry/px dropbox. If you click there, while your rectangle is marked, you get sharp corners immediately. Fastest way, imho.

Comment: Thank you, I admit I've never used the *Make corners sharp* button. I've updated my answer.

Comment: "Make corners sharp" or adjusting Rx/Ry is not enough: it will only make the upper left corner sharp. You also need to have Miter join selected for the other corners to become sharp.

Comment: The answer was related to a rectangle without a stroke. For the strokes you need to apply a proper join for the corners (Miter in this case). See my previous comment on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak English. but I will try to explain as clear as possible 
1. create a square

[image: square]

2. add a stroke to the square so it looks like this

[image]

3. then click path > stroke to path

4 path > break apart and you will get something similar to

[image]

5. then delete the outer box and you get something similar to this
   [image]

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In the Fill and Stroke module, go to:
Stroke Style > Join > {click the square corner} > {in the box next to it, set the default '0.00' to '7.50'}

That is what I had to do to get square corners. None of the other icons or settings worked.