# Sharpen Corners of Path

Tags: inkscape, path

A while ago I stumbled upon a webpage that demonstrated how to sharpen the round corners of a rectangular path. Basically you would just pull the nodes of the corners across till they intersected and then somehow select that piece and delete it. For the life of me I cannot find that webpage again nor can I remember the keystrokes used to select the piece to be deleted.

So can someone please assist me with a method to sharpen round corners of a rectangular path or to delete the below piece as indicated by the circle:

[image: Rectangle]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Greymatrix. If you are working on a [rectangle](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Rectangles.html), your question is similar to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81988/how-to-get-rid-of-rounded-edges-in-inkskape; if you are working on a path (your picture seems to be a path) see this: https://superuser.com/questions/640954/inkscape-rounding-corners-of-shapes.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini, thank you very much for the welcome. It’s not everyday you experience such hospitality on Stack Exchange site. As for the links you provided, the second one was successful in helping me sharpen rounded edges. I remember now that you first have to Path > Union and then Path > Break-apart. This makes it possible to select those pieces protruding from the edges and delete them and all their corresponding nodes completely. Thank you again! I was pulling my hair out with this so you can imagine my relief.

Comment: @ReginaldGreyling - do you know you can answer your own question? You could turn your comment into an answer and you can even select your own answer as best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways this could be done.

If the shape is a rectangle (not converted to paths), then there are controls for the corner radii, which you can click and drag. Obviously this would affect all the corners, which isn't helpful if you want to edit just one corner.

If the curved rectangle has been converted to paths, you could add a node inside the curve, convert it to a corner point, and click and drag it to the corner.  Adding guides, and switching on snapping to bounding boxes will help keep it accurate.

Note: double clicking with the Edit Paths by Nodes tool (F2), adds a node. And double clicking the Corner Point icon, creates a corner point without handles.

[image]

Here's another way, just turn one of the existing curve nodes to a corner mode, and drag it to the corner.

[image]

Comment: This method is so much easier and simpler! It also opened up a whole new world of methods for different tasks in Inkscape. Thank you @BillyKerr!

Comment: what if the corner is not a right angle (90°)? The handles cannot work here

Comment: @Ooker - if the corner is not a right angle, then you could just add guides to do it. [see example](https://imgur.com/1fOssz7)

Answer (score 0):

If you have rounded rectangle whenever you select the tool , draw a rectangle and then right click on it,choose fill and stroke options . Now, you can adjust it's radius (mentioned as "join" in Inkscape) into sharp one.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately this won't work for the OP's rectangle shape because it is a path without a stroke, and a rounded rectangle which has been converted to paths.  The join attribute in the Stroke Style panel only affects stroked paths at corner nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can scale the corner in on itself. Select the points next to the corner you want and scale frpm the opposite corners scale arrow.

[image]

**Image 1**: Scaling corner in on itself

Nifty trick. But only really works because of the shape of the underlying object. You can then use shapebuilder to kill of the excess.